# Radius of convergence of series given radius of convergence of another series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm hoping someone might be able to verify my solution to the following problem:

> Suppose that the series $\sum c_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R$.
>   Find the radius of convergence of the $\sum n^p c_n z^n$.

**My solution**: Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence of coefficients for the series. We have $(a_n) = (n^pc_n)_n$. Using the ratio test,

$$
L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^p c_n}{(n+1)^pc_{n+1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^p}{(n+1)^p} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} = R \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^p = 1.
$$

Thus, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: You cannot apply the ratio test in general.

Comment: Wait why is that?

Comment: There is no such theroem as "For *any* power series the raidus of convergence is given by $\lim\frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}$." You cannot assume thet $\lim \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}$ exists - think of $c_n=1+(-1)^n$. Go for $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. But is the radius of convergence $1$?

Comment: Now I'm getting $R$ for the radius of convergence, using the method suggested by Hagen. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^p|c_n|}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^p\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=1\cdot\frac{1}{R},
$$
hence the radius of convergence is $R$.